# Parse string into nullable numeric type (1 or 2 liner)

Tags: c#, .net

**Scenario**

Parse a string into a nullable numeric type.  If the parse is unsuccessful, the result should be null; otherwise the result should be the parsed value.

**Question**

To accomplish this, I have always used the following simple but lengthily annoying method:

```
string numericString = "...";

decimal? numericValue;
decimal temp;
if (decimal.TryParse(numericString, out temp))
{
    numericValue = temp;
}
else
{
    numericValue = null;
}
```

I use the above method because **the following doesn't compile**:

```
decimal temp;
decimal? numericValue = decimal.TryParse(numericString, out temp) ? temp : null;
```

Does anybody know of a version of the first bit of code that is as short, tidy, and readable as the second bit?  I know I could always write an extension method that encapsulates the first bit of code, but I'm wondering if there is any way to do what I want without an extension method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice one liner using more recent C# features would be:

```
var numericValue = decimal.TryParse(numericString, out var temp) ? temp : default(decimal?);
```

Comment: I asked this question forever ago and since then, this answer is closest to how I have done it since then. In the ternary expression, I prefer to put the cast on the first expression and put null as the second expression. Of all the variations, this way uses the fewest characters and in my opinion is still readable.

Answer (score 49):

One simple explicit typecast makes it compilable:

```
decimal temp;
// typecast either 'temp' or 'null'
decimal? numericValue =
  decimal.TryParse(numericString, out temp) ? temp : (decimal?)null;
```

Another option is to use the `default` operator on the desired nullable type:

```
decimal temp;
// replace null with default
decimal? numericValue =
  decimal.TryParse(numericString, out temp) ? temp : default(decimal?);
```

Comment: or `? (decimal?)temp : null;` just to add another look.

Comment: @Ondrej if you switch `(decimal?)null` to `default(decimal?)`, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @Dan, you can change it in your own code anyway, so you might as well accept the answer now...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Good point.  It's not like I'm trying to strike a deal.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this is that it can throw an `InvalidCastException`.  If you use `as decimal?`, it returns a null if the cast fails.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9, there's no way this code will cause an InvalidCastException... `(decimal?)null` will just return null.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the edit. However, I extended it a bit more, so the code is consistent with the introductory wording.

Answer (score 13):

I'd do something like this:

```
public delegate bool TryParseDelegate<T>(string str, out T value);

public static T? TryParseOrNull<T>(TryParseDelegate<T> parse, string str) where T : struct
{
    T value;
    return parse(str, out value) ? value : (T?)null;
}

decimal? numericValue = TryParseOrNull<decimal>(decimal.TryParse, numericString);
```

Or you could make it an extension method:

```
public static T? TryParseAs<T>(this string str, TryParseDelegate<T> parse) where T : struct
{
    T value;
    return parse(str, out value) ? value : (T?)null;
}

decimal? numericValue = numericString.TryParseAs<decimal>(decimal.TryParse);
```

Comment: +1 for a generic method that could be used for `DateTime`, `bool`, `int`, `long`, `double`, etc.

Comment: With the introduction of Generic Math, all built in numeric types implement `IParseable<T>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iparsable-1?view=net-7.0 So `T? TryParseAs<T>(this string str) where T : IParsable<T> => ...`

Answer (score 6):

Just factorize it to an extension method:

```
public static decimal? ParseDecimal(this string s)
{
    decimal d;
    if (decimal.TryParse(s, out d))
        return d;
    return null;
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
numericValue = numericString.TryParseDecimal();
```

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
decimal? numericValue = 
    decimal.TryParse(numericString, out temp) ? temp : null as decimal?;
```

This makes numericValue `null` if the cast fails, and is nice and clean.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that temp is a decimal and null...is null. Because they are not of the same type, the comparison between the two fails and you get an error.

Try either:

```
decimal? numericValue = decimal.TryParse(numericString, out temp) ? (decimal?)temp : null;
```

or

```
decimal? numericValue = decimal.TryParse(numericString, out temp) ? (decimal?)temp : (decimal?)null;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should wrap it in a method for better readability:

```
private decimal? ParseOrDefault(string decimalAsString, decimal? defaultIfInvalidString=null)
{
    decimal result;
    if (decimal.TryParse(decimalAsString, out result))
        return result;
    return defaultIfInvalidString;
}

[Test]
public void ParseOrDefaultTest()
{
    decimal? actual = ParseOrDefault("12", null);
    Assert.AreEqual(12m,actual);

    actual = ParseOrDefault("Invalid string", null);
    Assert.AreEqual(null, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

decimal? weight = decimal.TryParse(weightEditText.Text, out var tempWeight) ? tempWeight : default(decimal?)